# How to get SELECTED PAGE Numbers to Print only Selected Pages in PrintRange.Selection?

Tags: vb.net

I'm developing a database application in VB.NET. I have multiple-page reports, e.g., 10 pages.

I want to print only few pages, not all.  For example, I want to print pages no 3, 5 and 8 only which I specify in the Print Dialog's Page Range's Text Box while Selection (Radio button) option is selected. How can I access these page numbers in code to write the code to print only the specified pages in PrintDocument_PrintPage()? By default it Prints All Pages... it seems like .Net Framework doesn't handle selected pages itself. So we need to do a bit of coding in PrintRange.Selection condition.

[image: Screenshot of Print Dialog]

My Code is....

```
Dim intCurrentPage As Integer = 1

Private Sub PrintDocument_PrintPage(sender As Object, e As PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument.PrintPage 

If PrintDocument.PrinterSettings.PrintRange = PrintRange.AllPages Then

    'Code for printing All Pages

 **ElseIf PrintDocument.PrinterSettings.PrintRange = PrintRange.Selection Then**

     'Code for printing Only Selected Pages
     **'Here I Want Your Help... What is the method or function that returns the selected page numbers
     'in an Integer Array so that you can use some logic like this**

      Dim intOneOfSelectedPages() as Integers

      intOneOfSelectedPages = GetSelectedPages() 'Get All Selected Pages 

      For index = 0 To intOneOfSelectedPages.Length -1

          If intCurrentPage = intOneOfSelectedPages(index) Then

            'Code For Printing Current Page
         End If 
      Next

     intCurrentPage +=1

**End If**

End Sub
```

If anyone knows the method to be used to access selected pages in Print Dialog, please let me know!

Comment: I think you're meant to choose the "Pages" radio button, not the "Selection" radio button. "Selection" would be the pages selected in the document (and I don't know how to do that either).

Comment: Thanks Andrew. I have now realized that this text box on the Print Dialog is for Pages only not for Selection. It seems like there is no way to specify Multiple Random Pages through Print Dialog Box. Because in Pages you can either specify One Page or a Range of Pages which can be accessed by calling (PrintDocument).PrinterSettings.FromPage and ToPage!

Comment: You could investigate the "Remarks" section of [PrinterSettings.PrintRange Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.printing.printersettings.printrange?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) in case that makes it any clearer(!). Did you set the [PrintDialog.AllowSomePages Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.printdialog.allowsomepages?view=netcore-3.1&viewFallbackFrom=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1)?

Comment: I had already read the Microsoft's Documentation. It says "The selected pages are printed" if Selection property is true. But it doesn't explain where to select those pages. This is how pathetic Microsoft's documentation is! I was wondering how to find selected pages in code? But it seems like you cannot select pages through Print Dialog. You have to do it yourself...so I'm not using this option. So what I did is I set the AllowSelection to False and AllowSomePages to True which is the only alternate.